# managed profile on a second user

Tags: android, android-managed-profile

I tried to use the BasicManagedProfile sample provided by Goggle to set a Managed Profile. When I use it on the Primary User, it is working fine. But if I create a secondary user and try to install the app also, an error occurs. It says that the Managed Profils have to be set by the owner of the device. How can I set a Managed Profile on a second user ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the documentations, the Managed Profile can only be enabled by the primary user.

Although we called it as 'Managed Profile' its pretty similar in the inside process to another secondary user. In fact it is similar to having a secondary user in the same launcher!
So the same rules of creating secondary users are applied when creating the managed profile.

According to the multi-user feature of Android OS, only the Primary User can create other users (which are secondary users). So the same rule applies here and only the Primary user can enable the managed profile (which is very closer to creating another secondary user).

Thanks.